# IO/File In VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm working with text files. Actually one file, where I have to copy information to it. I'm using streamReader and streamWriter. But I'm having an error whenver I close the file and try to open it again. I can't open it again to start writing from where I stopped, and if I use the same IO writer in any other sub method, I get a run-time error message saying that file is being used. Is there any way that I can close and open the text file separately at anytime?

```
Dim ioFile As New StreamWriter(filename, False)
'code
iofile.close()
```

There is no problem in how many times I read or Write in between , but whenever I close it, can't open it.

Comment: Please post your code. Are you closing the streams properly?

Comment: You are doing battle with other processes on your machine that want to read the file.  And prevent you from re-creating it while they do.  Virus scanner, search indexer, those kind of programs.  Rename the file first.

Comment: @Hans Passant  The access issue kicks in when I try to access the file from a different sub in the same application. I'm printing many times to the same file. For example, I can't call a sub to use it anywhere because then it say the Path file : c:\desktop\text.txt is being used by another program. I'm stuck , I can only write the program in one sub.

Comment: Your code snippet is quite inadequate.  No, you can't open the same file twice.  Pass ioFile as an argument to the other sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the streamwriter in a using clause, and set AutoFlush to True:

```
Using ioFile As New StreamWriter(filename, True)
    ioFile.AutoFlush = True
    'Code
End Using
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Since im writing many times one after the other, it cleans the one before and keeps the last. Anyway thanks for trying.

Comment: It is overwriting because the append parameter is set to false.  Change that parameter to true and it will append to the file with each write.